# Exec_bad_access when dismissing View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

for some time I'm struggling to find the solution to this, I've searched google, stackoverflow but couldn't solve this.

I have 2 view controllers (let's call them VC1 and VC2), I can change between them with no problem. To present VC2 I use:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* ctrl = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"histListID"];
[self presentViewController:ctrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To get back to VC1 I use:

```
- (IBAction)backPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

VC2 contains a Table View and after I delete some cell if I try to get back to VC1 I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1). I've never had to handle this before and I know it may have to do  with something somewhere in my code. But I don't really know how to interpret it. Does it have something to do with my tableView? Am I doing something wrong when dismissing the controller?

[image: Thread 1]

If you need more code please ask, I really need to solve it.

PS: I have ARC turned on.

EDIT: Code used to delete cell

```
    [self deleteItemAt:chosenItem];
    [tableView reloadData];
```

Basically what deleteItemAt does is delete some objects from arrays:

```
- (void)deleteItemAt:(int)index
{

    [self.histModel deleteFileAtIndex:index];
    if ([self isWeekSelected]) {
        [self updateWeekDic];
    }else{
        [self updateMonthDic];
    }
    [callout dismissAnimated:YES];
}
```

Sorry if it doesn't do it correctly I didn't wrote that part of the code, but I don't think it has to do with deleting the cell.

Comment: Does it crash if you don't delete the cell ?

Comment: Please show the code with which the cells are deleted.

Comment: No, it doesn't crash if I don't delete.

Comment: Code added to the question

Comment: You code to delete should be updating the tableview, too. Can you show us that part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you dismiss a viewController make sure to set all delegates to nil. The stack trace is showing a lot of objects being released and then tableview delegate callbacks. I suspect from this that its trying to call `[delegate canEditCellAtRowindex]` but the viewController has been dismissed and is no longer in the stack.

e.g.

```
[tableView setDelegate:nil];
[tableView setDataSource:nil];
```

Comment: I tried it, but I forgot to set the dataSource to nil! Thank you!

Also, here what I get now 

"reloading table view while we're in swipe to delete mode but we don't have a proper swipe to delete index path"

hm... well, no crash so fixed!

Comment: @LorenzoPiccoliMódolo It sounds like you have some conflicting logic in your code to do with timing. Just looked at the code you added and noticed your calling a reload directly after the function that deletes a row. You have animation turned on for the delete, which takes time to process, essentially your are running the delete and the reload at the same time on different threads. Try doing it another way, or if you must [tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; to break it up

Comment: Thank you! It did clarify a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion approved answer is not very good, because as it said in comments, you still have warning in console.
I would prefer call *[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO]* in view controller's *dealloc* or in *viewDidDisappear:*.